# Label sheets while importing multiple text files Excel VBA

Tags: text, excel, import, vba

I've been attempting to import multiple large text files onto multiple spreadsheets within the same workbook. Thanks to other posts on this site, I have cobbled together some VBA code that seems to do the job. Only problem is that since the data are unlabelled within the text files, it is difficult to tell them apart for analysis. As such, I would like to label each spreadsheet with the corresponding text file during the import process. The code I'm using is as follows.

Thanks!

```
Sub ImportManyTXTs()
Dim strFile As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
strFile = Dir("I:\test\*.txt")
Do While strFile <> vbNullString
Set ws = Sheets.Add
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & "I:\test\" & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = strFile
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(7, 9)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
strFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Edit: Managed to figure it out. Just added ws.Name = strFile after End With. Seems to work quite well.

Comment: Make sure you follow the rules for valid sheet names: [Your Sheet Names are Killing My Formulas](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2009/10/26/your-sheet-names-are-killing-my-formulas/)

Comment: Haha. Yeah. That wasn't a problem. Managed to figure it out. Just added ws.Name = strFile after End With. Seems to work quite well.

Comment: I suggest you enter your answer as an answer to the question and mark it as answered using the check mark. Yes you can provide your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. Just added ws.Name = strFile after End With. Seems to work quite well.