# importing multiple text files into separate Excel sheets in 1 Excel book using VBA

Tags: excel, text, import, vba

I have written a VBA macro for importing many text files (from 1 folder) onto separate sheets in 1 Excel workbook.  All files read into each separate sheet just fine.  However, I am seeing a field placement issue.  The headers on each text file are the same.  But, the field values themselves sometimes get pushed down by a few fields.  So, not all fields values line up under their proper headers.  Can anybody suggest to me why this is happening?  I have tried seeing if it's a tab-delimited or a pipe-delimited issue, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
Sub MultipleTextFilesIntoExcelSheets()
    Dim i As Integer 'a counter to loop through the files in the folder
    Dim fname As String, FullName As String 'fname is the name of the file, and FullName is the name of its path
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'a workbook object for the workbook where the current macro is running

i = 0 'seed the counter

'get the name of the first text file
fname = Dir("C:\dummy_path\*txt")

'loop through the text files to put them onto separate sheets in the Excel book
While (Len(fname) > 0)
    'get the full path of the text file
    FullName = "C:\dummy_path\" & fname
    i = i + 1 'get ready for the next iteration

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & i) 'the current sheet

    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FullName, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
        .Name = "a" & i
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True    'we are using a tab-delimited file
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        fname = Dir
    End With
Wend
```

End Sub

Comment: VBA is treating the letter "f" as a tab delimiter.  Does anybody know why or how to fix it?

Comment: Any idea why I would be getting a "Subscript out of range" error when I run this code?  It does import the first txt file into the same sheet as my macro button, then the error on this line `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & i)`

Comment: Just found this piece of codes that works really well and labels each sheet with the txt filename [label-sheets-while-importing-multiple-text-files-excel-vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891733/label-sheets-while-importing-multiple-text-files-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

The "treating F as delimiter" problem is because of this line:

```
.TextFileOtherDelimiter = False
```

Removing it makes the VBA work as expected. The default value for TextFileOtherDelimiter should be "null" rather than False I think.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.ConsecutiveDelimiter = False` to `.ConsecutiveDelimiter = True`

**SOME DETAILS :** This probably happens due to the fact that there might be more than one tab delimiting the "columns". Changing this parameter will allow for multiple tabs to be accepted as one.

Comment: Doing so still produces the same effect, but in the opposite direction.  Some of my fields aren't necessarily populated on my text files.  So, by setting the Consecutive Delimiter to be True, it pushes field values that are after these empty fields down into the wrong fields.  There must be something else I need to change.

Comment: I've had this kind of issue as well, the only way I figured how to get around this problem was to use the other delimitation tool, namely the fixed-width delimiter. This will allow you to "cut a new column" every x,y,z,etc characters.

Comment: And even then, it might not be a proper fix for your issue. Another solution that comes to mind is implementing a "correction" macro that would insert / remove empty spaces according to predefined rules.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions.  When I import each text file manually (via Excel's text file import wizard), everything looks fine; all field values line up in their proper columns.  So, there must be something that the wizard has built-in that I am not replicating in this macro.

Comment: I just noticed a pattern.  Whenever the macro encounters the letter "f", it pushes all text after it into the next field (and it doesn't print the "f").  This is weird.

Comment: Try recording a macro while you do it manually, and then compare the result's parameters with the ones you have. When there's a difference, take the parameter produced by the macro recorder. If you need any pointers on using the macro recorder, I will give you some pointers.